# Is there a method to calculate the total duration a gif plays?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, gif

I want to calculate the total duration a gif plays. It can be either duration of a gif or frame count of the gif. Have tried using FLAnimatedImage, SDWebImage and YYImage but can't really attain what I am looking for. The gif is loaded from remote url and then I want to calculate the duration it plays.

Comment: You can achieve this pretty simply. When the gif is displayed start an NSTimer with an interval that conforms to your desired accuracy for example every 2ms. Then stop the timer when the view is dismissed. Essentially utilising the NSTimer as a stopwatch to calculate the total duration the gif is displayed.

Comment: @torinpitchers Why would you use an `[NS]Timer` to see how long something takes?

Comment: Is this the apt solution @torinpitchers

Comment: @rmaddy any other solution you would like to propose?

Comment: @maddy The clue is in the name, its a timer used to time things. here is three examples of using NSTimer as a stopwatch to time things. http://rshankar.com/simple-stopwatch-app-in-swift/, https://creativedigital.co.nz/swift-3-programming-a-simple-stopwatch/, https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/stopwatch-tutorial/. What would you advise to use instead?

Comment: @torinpitchers An NSTimer is used to trigger a selector after a specific interval. This can be done once or repeated after each interval. It is not used to keep track of time or duration. Use `Date` (before and after and calculate the difference) or one of a few other functions specific to tracking clock time.

Comment: any particular example?

Answer (score 0):

This is the function that returns the total duration in GIF time units (1 unit = 10 msec).

`data` is a pointer to GIF data, `size` is its size.

```
long Duration(uint8_t *data, long size) {
    long desc, time = 0;
    uint8_t *buff;

    if ((size > 13) && data && (data[0] == 71) && (data[1] == 73)
    &&  (data[2] == 70) && (data[3] == 56) && (data[5] == 97)
    && ((data[4] == 55) || (data[4] == 57))) {
        buff = data + 13 + ((data[10] & 0x80)? 6 << (data[10] & 7) : 0);
        if ((size -= buff - data) > 0)
            while ((desc = *buff++) != 0x3B) {
                size--;
                if (desc == 0x2C) {
                    desc = 9 + ((buff[8] & 0x80)? 6 << (buff[8] & 7) : 0);
                    buff += desc;
                    if ((size -= desc) <= 0)
                        break;
                }
                else if ((desc == 0x21) && (*buff == 0xF9))
                    time += *(uint16_t*)(buff + 3);
                buff++;
                if (--size <= 0)
                    break;
                do {
                    buff += (desc = 1 + *buff);
                    if ((size -= desc) <= 0)
                        return time;
                } while (desc > 1);
            }
    }
    return time;
}
```

This function parses GIF images by hand, extracting frame delay information and summing it.